# DataTables parameter error with nested JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm using DataTables 1.10.4 in a .NET MVC application.  I'm getting a "Requested Unknown Parameter" error when referencing any nested data.  I've reviewed the nested objects example on datatables.net and my code looks pretty similar.

Any help would really be appreciated.

columns DataTable attribute:

```
 "columns":
         [
               {"data": "OrgID"},
               { "data": "OrgName" },
               { "data": "Funds.FundCode"},
               { "data": "Funds.YtdBudget" },
               { "data": "Funds.YtdActivity" },
               { "data": "Funds.Encumbrance" },
               { "data": "Funds.AvailableBalance" }
         ]
```

JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "OrgID": "223906",
      "OrgName": "CAS IT Operations",
      "Funds": [
        {
          "FundCode": "001100",
          "FundTitle": "",
          "YtdBudget": 2468595,
          "YtdActivity": 1505559.98,
          "Encumbrance": 835310.34,
          "AvailableBalance": 127724.68
        }
      ],
      "YtdBudget": 2468595,
      "YtdActivity": 1505559.98,
      "Encumbrance": 835310.34,
      "AvailableBalance": 127724.68
    }
  ],
  "iTotalRecords": 1,
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": 1
}
```

Error Message:

```
DataTables warning: table id=ajaxTable = Requested unknown parameter 'Funds.FundCode for row 0.
```

Comment: `Funds` is an array. I'm not familiar with DataTables, but that structure would suggest a table within a table. You would need to access it with `"data": "Funds[0].FundCode"},` Alternatively it should be `"Funds": { "FundCode": "001100", ..., "AvailableBalance": 127724.68 },`

Comment: I was looking at the example of DataTables nested object data here [link]http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html - in the example, "hr:" is a flat object, which isn't very useful for displaying hierarchical data.  I'll keep looking for an example of that.

Comment: Looking at the linked article, it would seem that you need to use `{ "data": "Funds.0" },` in order to display the `FundCode` value of `Funds`, or `{ "data": "Funds.5" },` to display the `AvailableBalance` of `Funds` (i.e. if its an array, use the index of the property)